# The class of all sets of the form F \ E, where E is a subset of F and both are in a lattice of sets, form a semiring

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This question is found in section 5 exercise 2 in Halmos's *Measure Theory*.

### Definitions:

A lattice of sets is a class $\mathscr{L}$ such that $\emptyset \in \mathscr{L}$ and such that if $E,F \in \mathscr{L}$ then both $E\cap F$ and $E \cup F$ are in $\mathscr{L}$. A semiring is a non-empty class of sets $\mathscr{P}$ such that (1) if $E,F \in \mathscr{P}$ then $E \cap F \in \mathscr{P}$ and (2) if $E,F \in \mathscr{P}$ and $E\subseteq F$ then there is a finite class $\{C_0 , C_1, ... , C_n\}$ of sets in $\mathscr{P}$ such that $E = C_0 \subseteq C_1 \subseteq ... \subseteq C_n = F$ and $D_i = C_i \setminus C_{i-1} \:$ is in $\mathscr{P}$ for $i = 1, ... ,n$.

### The Question:

Let $\mathscr{P} := \{F \setminus E \: | \: E,F \in \mathscr{L} \text{ and } E \subseteq F\}$ for a given lattice $\mathscr{L}$. Then $\mathscr{P}$ is a semiring.

(I am primarily concerned with proving the first criterion, that the intersection is in the family)

### What I've Tried:

There are two ways I tried to solve this problem. First, I tried to express the intersection of $A, B \in \mathscr{P}$ as the proper difference of two sets:
$$A\cap B = A \cup B \: \setminus \: A\Delta B$$ where $A \Delta B$ is the symmetric difference. The problem then reduces to trying to show $A \Delta B \in \mathscr{L}$. I am able to show the both $A \cup B$ and $A \Delta B$ are in $\mathscr{P}$, but I need two sets in $\mathscr{L}$.

The second way is by noticing that as long as $A \cap B$ is in $\mathscr{L}$ then the condition is satisfied, so the problem becomes: Show $(F_1 \setminus E_1) \cap (F_2 \setminus E_2 ) \in \mathscr{L}$, but this seems just as intractable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(F_1\setminus E_1)\cap ((F_2\setminus E_2)=(F_1\cap F_2) \setminus (E_1 \cup E_2)$. [Just verify that each side is contained in the other]. Now use the fact that $C\setminus D=C\setminus (C\cap D)$.

Take $C=F_1\cap F_2$ and $D=E_1\cup E_2$. Can you verify that $C\cap D$ belongs to $\mathcal L$?

Comment: I see the solution. We have $A \cap B = (F_1 \cap F_2) \setminus ((F_1 \cap F_2) \cap (E_1 \cup E_2 ))$. Thus the latter term is contained in the former, so the difference is proper and also each term is in $\mathscr{L}$. I see the difference is either empty (in the case $E_1$ and $E_2$ are on opposite sides of $A \Delta B$) or we have a nonempty set in $\mathscr{P}$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}(F_1 \setminus E_1) \cap (F_2 \setminus E_2 )&=F_1\cap E_1^c\cap F_2\cap E_2^c\\&=(F_1\cap F_2)\cap(E_1\cup E_2)^c\\&=(F_1\cap F_2)\setminus(E_1\cup E_2).\end{align}$$
And the condition $E\subseteq F$ in the definition of $\mathscr P$ may be dropped, since $\forall E,F\in\mathscr L\quad F\setminus E=F\setminus E',$ where $E'=E\cap F\subseteq F$ and $E'\in\mathscr L.$